# EF Reverse POCO Generator: Failed to load provider EntityClient

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, poco, entity-framework-6

I'm using 
[EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/) in VS2012

VS2012...

Here's my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\SomeDatabase.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

- installed nuget EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact
- installed Entity Framework 6.1.0 Tools for Visual Studio
- added System.Data.Entity to my references

Updated the .tt file to point to my connectionString and I get this error (warning) when I save::

Warning 1   Running transformation: Failed to load provider "System.Data.EntityClient" - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

So it is not generating any code. Any ideas?

here's a snippet of the Database.tt file:

```
<#@ include file="EF.Reverse.POCO.Core.ttinclude" #>
<#
    // v2.5.0
    // Please make changes to the settings below.
    // All you have to do is save this file, and the output file(s) is/are generated. Compiling does not regenerate the file(s).

    // Misc settings **********************************************************************************************************************
    // Namespace = ""; // Override the default namespace here
    DbContextName = "MyContext";
    ConnectionStringName = "Entities";  // Searches for this connection string in config files listed below
    ConfigurationClassName = "Configuration"; // Configuration, Mapping, Map, etc. This is appended to the Poco class name to configure the mappings.
    ConfigFilenameSearchOrder = new[] { "app.config", "web.config", "app.config.transform", "web.config.transform" }; // Add more here if required. The config files are searched for in the local project first, then the whole solution second.
    MakeClassesPartial = true;
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer, the problem was in the ConnectionString

should be as follows:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="Data Source=C:\StoreContainer.sdf"
      providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Great advice. As for me, my connetionstring had a provider-name of providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" - but really the issue was that **the Reverse POCO generator needs a code-first connectionstring**, I had merely added a model-first one because I was just gunning for the connectionstring and had thought that any one would do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, the problem was I **misspelled the ConnectionStringName** in the Database.tt file.

```
#@ include file="EF.Reverse.POCO.Core.ttinclude" #>
<#
// v2.14.3
// Please make changes to the settings below.
// All you have to do is save this file, and the output file(s) is/are generated. Compiling does not regenerate the file(s).

DbContextName = "MyDbContext";
DbContextInterfaceBaseClasses = "IDisposable";
DbContextBaseClass = "DbContext";
ConnectionStringName = "MyDbConnection";   //<--- THIS... I misspelled this..
```